# use the same credentials.json to access google drive/google sheet api in python

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I am write interface to access google api with google drive and google sheets. For each api, I follow [google api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) like google drive to create a **credentials.json** and using following code for no problem. But as interface, how can I just use one credentials.json file to access multiple api?

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client import client, tools
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('~/credentials.json', ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the project on google developer console has the diffrent apis enabled you can use the same file for which ever apis you want to access your just going to have to request access for each of them.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client import client, tools
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('~/credentials.json', 
              ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
serviceDrive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
serviceSheets = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
```

You then access each of your apis though their own service.  The user will be prompted to authenticate for both drive, and sheets when they login.

```
sheet = serviceSheets.spreadsheets()
results = serviceDrive.files().list(pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
```

Comment: it does not work. it is ok on google drive but error from google sheet `{HttpError}<HttpError 403 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets?alt=json returned "Google Sheets API has not been used in project xxxxxxx before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxxxx then retry.`

Comment: add visit the link, i still cannot enable google sheet in my gmail account. because it says i do not have permission

Comment: You need to enable it for your project in Google developer console (not your google account).  Figure out who created your credentials file and have them fix it.  This is unrelated to your question its just a setup issue.

Comment: You might find [this](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841?hl=en) useful on how to **ENABLE APIs** for your Google Cloud Projects